# replacing path using route object in nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url, nuxt.js, router

I want to go to this url:

```
myApp.com/search-page?name%5Bquery%5D=value
```

and the following code works well for it when I'm on the home page `myApp.com`:

```
this.$router.push({
  path: "search-page",
  query: { name: { query: `${this.value}` } }
});
```

But if I'm on a different page that has a path already like:

```
myApp.com/movies/id
```

when I use the same code with `$router.push` it takes me to this url:

```
myApp.com/movies/search-page?name%5Bquery%5D=value
```

As you can see there is an extra `movies/` in the URL which we don't want! How can I make it so no matter what my current path (URL) is, my `$router.push` method takes me to:

```
myApp.com/search-page?name%5Bquery%5D=value
```

Comment: you are pushing a "relative_path", instead of an "/absolute_path". you want the latter: `path: "/search-page"`

Comment: @IgorMoraru is probably right here.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `path` in `$router.push`. If you are in a nested page you also need to change the path value.

Instead use `name` so you don't have to specify path levels

```
this.$router.push({
  name: "search-page",
  query: { name: { query: `${this.value}` } }
});
```

In nuxt, the route names are basically the folder name generated to lower string and hyphens. So if you have folder like this and you want to access movies id route

```
pages/
--| movies
-----| _id.vue
```

You can access it by

```
this.$router.push({
      name: "movies-id",
      params: { 
         id: 1
      }    
});
```